# How to mark original parts of document ReadOnly in a RadRickTextBox

Tags: telerik, wpf-controls

I am pulling some Html from a database and using a HtmlFormatProvider to import that into a RadRichTextBox.  I then move the caret to the end of the document.

What I would like to do now is mark all of the text before the caret (the originally loaded text) as ReadOnly and allow the user to enter text below it.

But I need help using the ReadOnlyRanges in the RadRichTextBox.

Can someone show me how to protect the first part of my doc?

Answer (score 0):

Although more than a month old, I found this question to be interesting and decided to give it a go.

The easiest way of accomplishing it, is by selecting the text to be protected and calling the InsertReadOnlyRange method.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <telerik:RadRichTextBox
        x:Name="RichTextBox"
        IsSpellCheckingEnabled="False"
        Loaded="RichTextBox_Loaded" />
    <telerik:HtmlDataProvider
        RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=RichTextBox}"
        Html="{Binding Html, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string Html { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        Html = "<h1>You can't touch this (oh-oh oh oh oh-oh-oh)</h1>";
    }

    private void RichTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox.Document.Selection.SelectAll();
        RichTextBox.InsertReadOnlyRange();
        RichTextBox.Document.Selection.Clear();
    }
}
```

For more information, you can read the [Read Only Ranges](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radrichtextbox/features/read-only-ranges.html) article.